# Href migration from 1.x to 2.x?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I have the following href with php tag. It works on 1.x, i need to migrate to 2.x version.

```
 <a  href="<?=base_url('report/message/compose/{{student.StudentID}}')?>">test</a>
```

how to change to work on 2.x version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do it in this way.

```
<a  v-bind:href=" '<?=base_url('report/message/compose/')?>' + student.StudentID">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do this:

```
<a :href="'/report/message/compose/' + student.StudentID">test</a>
```

Comment: we cannot add the <?=base_url()?> there?

Comment: @user3391137 Why is this needed?

Comment: I'm calling this href from ("http://localhost/app/demo/school/student" ).
My base url is "http://localhost/app/demo" as given in base_url().So this href wants to link "http://localhost/app/demo/report/message/compose/' + student.StudentID". This is the reason why i appended the base_url().

Comment: is `base_url` an function, if yes, can you please add it for reference?

Comment: As you are said, i can accomplish it by using the url like :href=" '/app/demo/report/message/compose/' + student.StudentID". I dont.t prefer to append the '/app/demo/' to all url. That's why i'm calling this base_url().

Comment: base_url() is the buit-in function of codeigniter to get the base url of application.

Comment: Saurabh, Have you got the point that why i needs this base_url() here?